# Firefox Javascript Events Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-handling, closures, anonymous-function

I'm attempting to register an anonymous function when a user clicks a cell in an HTML table.  Here's some of the raw, unadulterated code:

```
document.getElementById(
    "course"+displayed_year_index+occurrences_indices[displayed_year_index]).onclick =
        eval("function() {PrintReceipt("+result.years[result_year_index].rul_code+");};");
```

Note the use of `eval`, since this sits in a loop and the anonymous function is different each time round.

Suffice to say, this works absolutely fine in Firefox 2.  But, Firefox 3 throws a 'Syntax Error', pointing inside the brackets after the word 'function'.

Does anybody have any smart ideas on how I can fix this?

---

Just to make it crystal clear what I'm attempting to do, here's a much simplified example:

```
for (index=0; index<4; index++) {
    document.getElementById("div"+index).onclick = 
        eval("function () {Foo(index);};");
}
```

In other words, I wish to trigger the same function with a different parameter value for each `div`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO closures should not be used in this case and there is no need to create a new function for each onlick (uses much more memory than necessary) and eval is the wrong answer.

You know that the element you are getting with getElementById is an object and that you can assign values to it?

```
for ( /* your definition */ ) {
  var e = document.getElementById(
    "course"+displayed_year_index+occurrences_indices[displayed_year_index]
  );
  e.rul_code = result.years[result_year_index].rul_code;
  e.onclick = PrintReceipt;
}
```

But you should define the PrintReceipt first:

```
function PrintReceipt() {
  //This function is called as an onclick handler, and "this" is a reference to the element that was clicked.
  if (this.rul_code === undefined) { return; }
  //Do what you want with this.rul_code
  alert (this.rul_code);
}
```

Comment: You are of course completely right.  Never use a sledgehammer to crack a nut eh?

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried something like this?

```
document.getElementById('course' + displayed_year_index + occurences_indices[displayed_year_index]) =
    function (nr)
    {
        return function () { PrintReceipt(nr) }
    } (result.years[result_year_index].rul_code);
```

Can you please post the loop to help us find the problem instead of making us guess what you're trying to do?

Comment: Good answer, but a link to a good explanation of closures would help so much. I understand your code but it still scares me ;) Someone who doesn't know what a closure is wouldn't have a chance. Unfortunately I haven't yet seen a clear, concise explanation of closures anywhere online :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to assign to the onclick event, and I can't pass a parameter to the anonymous function because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Use closures like Tom suggested.

Heres a good explanation by John Resig: [How Closures Work](http://ajaxian.com/downloads/books/javascriptninja/JavaScriptNinja_ch3_Article1.pdf) (pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is the direction that you would want to go:

```
document.getElementById("course"+displayed_year_index+occurrences_indices[displayed_year_index]).addeventlistener("click",  function() {
    var current_rul_code = result.years[result_year_index].rul_code;
    PrintReceipt(current_rul_code);
}, true);
```

This should cause each to onclick event to be created within a different scope (each iteration of the loop).  [Closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html) will take care of the rest.

Comment: This doesn't work, because the parameter to PrintReceipt needs to be a constant when called by the onclick.

Comment: It should not need to be a constant, because the function will be called within it's original scope when the event fires.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your example as stated, but it doesn't work.  This is because result.years[result_year_index].rul_code is not in scope when the function is called from the onClick.  What I actually need is the value of the variable (13208 in this case) to be passed to the function.